# Java JPanel setBorder and antialiasing not working

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d, antialiasing

I am currently writing a chess app in Java, but i have some problems with creating border for tiles and with image smoothing.

**EDIT:**
Problem with borders was solved. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37032059/6291224) below;

**Result:**

[image]

As you can see there is a jaggy edges on chess pieces and tile border is missing.
However, antialiasing is working if i add getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH), but this slows down my app and icons looks ugly when i resize window.

[image: With getScaledInstance()]

**My code:**

Table class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Table {
    private final BoardPanel boardPanel;
    private final Board chessBoard;

    private final static Dimension OUTER_FRAME_DIMENSION = new Dimension(650, 650);
    private final static Dimension MIN_FRAME_DIMENSION = new Dimension(550, 550);

    public Table(Board chessBoard) {
        this.chessBoard = chessBoard;
        boardPanel = new BoardPanel(chessBoard);

        JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("Chess");
        gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gameFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gameFrame.setSize(OUTER_FRAME_DIMENSION);
        gameFrame.setMinimumSize(MIN_FRAME_DIMENSION);


        gameFrame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
        gameFrame.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        gameFrame.pack();
        gameFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        final JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(createFileMenu());
        menuBar.add(createPreferencesMenu());
        return menuBar;
    }

    private JMenu createFileMenu() {
        final JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        final JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);
        return fileMenu;
    }

    private JMenu createPreferencesMenu() {
        final JMenu preferencesMenu = new JMenu("Preferences");
        final JMenuItem flipBoardMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Flip Board");
        flipBoardMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boardPanel.reverse();
                boardPanel.drawBoard();
            }
        });
        preferencesMenu.add(flipBoardMenuItem);
        return preferencesMenu;
    }
}
```

BoardPanel class:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater;
import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton;
import static javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton;

class BoardPanel extends JPanel {
    private final Board chessBoard;
    private final TilePanel[][] boardTiles;

    private Point start; // first click
    private Point target;  // second click

    private static final Dimension BOARD_PANEL_DIMENSION = new Dimension(650, 650);
    private static final Dimension TILE_PANEL_DIMENSION = new Dimension(100, 100);

    BoardPanel(Board chessBoard) {
        super(new GridLayout(Board.N, Board.N));
        this.chessBoard = chessBoard;
        this.boardTiles = new TilePanel[Board.N][Board.N];

        ImageManager.readPieceImages();
        setPreferredSize(BOARD_PANEL_DIMENSION);
        fillBoard();
        validate();
    }

    private void fillBoard() {
        for (int x = 0; x < Board.N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < Board.N; y++) {
                TilePanel tilePanel = new TilePanel(new Point(x, y));
                boardTiles[x][y] = tilePanel;
            }
        }
        for (int i = Board.N; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Board.N; j++) {
                add(boardTiles[j][i - 1]);
            }
        }
        validate();
    }

    void drawBoard() {
        removeAll();
        for (int i = Board.N; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Board.N; j++) {
                boardTiles[j][i - 1].drawTile();
                add(boardTiles[j][i - 1]);
            }
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    void reverse() {
        // revers coloums
        for (int col = 0; col < Board.N; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < Board.N / 2; row++) {
                TilePanel temp = boardTiles[row][col];
                boardTiles[row][col] = boardTiles[Board.N - row - 1][col];
                boardTiles[Board.N - row - 1][col] = temp;
            }
        }

        // reverse rows
        for (int row = 0; row < Board.N; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < Board.N / 2; col++) {
                TilePanel temp = boardTiles[row][col];
                boardTiles[row][col] = boardTiles[row][Board.N - col - 1];
                boardTiles[row][Board.N - col - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    private class TilePanel extends JPanel {
        private final Tile tile;
        private Image pieceImage;


        TilePanel(final Point p) {
            super(new GridBagLayout());
            this.tile = chessBoard.getTile(p);

            setPreferredSize(TILE_PANEL_DIMENSION);
            setColor();
            setPieceIcon();
            highlightBorder();

            addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (isRightMouseButton(e)) {
                        start = null;
                        target = null;
                    } else if (isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                        if (start == null) { // first click
                            start = tile.isOccupied() ? tile.getPosition() : null;
                            System.out.println(tile);
                        } else { // second click
                            target = tile.getPosition();
                            Move move = new Move(chessBoard, start, target);
                            if (move.isValid()) {
                                System.out.println(move);
                                chessBoard.movePiece(start, target);
                                System.out.println(chessBoard);
                                repaint();
                            }
                            start = null;
                            target = null;
                        }
                    }
                    invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            drawBoard();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

                }
            });
            validate();
        }

        private void highlightLegalMoves() {
            if (start != null && chessBoard.getTile(start).isOccupied()) {
                Piece piece = chessBoard.getTile(start).getPiece();
                for (Move move : piece.generateMoves(chessBoard, start)) {
                    if (tile == move.getStartTile()) {
                        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(255, 255, 102)));
                    } else if (tile == move.getTargetTile()) {
                        setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 102));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void highlightBorder() {
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        }

        private void setPieceIcon() {
            removeAll();
            if (tile.isOccupied()) {
                Piece piece = tile.getPiece();
                pieceImage = ImageManager.getPieceImage(piece.toString());
            } else {
                pieceImage = null;
            }
        }

        private void drawTile() {
            setColor();
            setPieceIcon();
            highlightLegalMoves();
            highlightBorder();
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

        final AffineTransform getTransform() {
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
            at.scale(getWidth() / 900.0,
                    getHeight() / 900.0);
            return at;
        }

        private void setColor() {
            Color light = new Color(247, 236, 202);
            Color dark = new Color(102, 68, 46);
            boolean black
                    = (tile.getPosition().x % 2 == 0) == (tile.getPosition().y % 2 == 0);
            setBackground(black ? dark : light);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.transform(getTransform());
            AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);


            at.setToTranslation(10, 0);
            g2d.drawImage(pieceImage, at, null);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything I can fix this issue? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fix borders by deleting g2d.dispose from paintComponent() method. But i still have problem with antialiasing.

Answer (score 0):

> icons looks ugly when i resize window.

1. So don't dynamically scale the icons. Or,
2. don't allow the board to be rescaled.
3. Maybe you can use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which allows you to keep the original proportion when then Icon is scaled. Note, this class doesn't set an rendering hints so you may need to add that.